# How to properly escape quotes in powershell v2?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, windows-7, escaping, powershell-2.0

How do you properly escape quotes in powershell v2 (called from within a batch file)?

I have tried:

```
powershell -Command "(gc file1.txt) -join "`n" | Out-File file2.txt"
```

and

```
powershell -Command "(gc file1.txt) -join ""`n"" | Out-File file2.txt"
```

and

```
powershell -Command "(gc file1.txt) -join '"`n`" | Out-File file2.txt"
```

but they all fail.

<sup>*Editor's note*: The purpose of the command is to transform Windows CRLF line breaks to Unix LF-only ones, so as to create a file that will be processed on Linux.</sup>

Comment: Don't stop at two quotes, use three ```"""`n"""``` and you'll succeed!

Comment: More to the point, backtick-n in PowerShell is documented as expanding to CR/LF in Windows, which sort of moots the exercise. If the querent truly wishes to separate the lines with _only_ a LF, he should use `[char]10` as the join character. (and how do you make backtick-n into "typed" text in comments?)

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Uh oh... all the examples I found claimed `\`n` was just an LF.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard - While [`Get-Help about_Special_Characters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters) does call `\`n` "New Line", it says that it inserts a "line break", and if you run a hex dump on the result, you'll see `0D 0A`.

Comment: **`"\`n"` is _always_ just LF (the _single_ character with Unicode code point `10` (`0xA`))**, as evidenced by the following statements returning `$True`: `"\`n".length -eq 1` and `[char] 10 -eq [char] "\`n"`.
[`Get-Help about_Special_Characters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters) isn't explicit about this, unfortunately:  it mentions "new line" and "line break", without mentioning what specific character [sequence] that represents. (In PowerShell, a LF by itself is just as valid a line break as CRLF is).

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: I've cleaned up our exchange here and replaced it with a focused rebuttal. If you still feel you are correct, I encourage you to create a _question_ (e.g, "What does "\`n" expand to in PowerShell?") and self-answer with a _verifiable example_ of when `"\`n"` expands to CRLF. Personally, I would love to find out if I'm missing something (and I'll gladly remove my comments here / fix my answer below if proven wrong).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**From a batch file (`cmd.exe`), you must `\`-escape embedded `"` instances**
(even though PowerShell-*internally* it is `` ` `` (the backtick) that serves as the escape character):

<sup>As [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) points out in a comment on the question, in *Windows PowerShell* **using `"""` to embed a single `"` is also an option**.
However, given that most command-line utilities support `\"`, `\"` is easier to remember. However, both `"""` and `\"` can *break* on the `cmd.exe` side, in which case **`"^""`** (sic) is required (**`""` in *PowerShell (Core) 7+***).</sup>

```
powershell -Command "(gc file1.txt) -join \"`n\" | Set-Content -NoNewLine file2.txt"
```

Note:

- `Set-Content -NoNewline` requires **PSv5+**.
- **`Set-Content` writes "ANSI"-encoded files by default** (e.g., based on code page Windows-1252 on US-English systems); use the `-Encoding` parameter to change that.

  - Since you're only dealing with *strings*, `Set-Content` is preferable to `Out-File`, which is only needed if you have non-string objects that must have PowerShell's default formatting applied to them first.
- Consider using `powershell -NoProfile ...` to suppress loading of PowerShell's profile files, both for faster execution and for a more predictable execution environement.

---

**PSv2 solution:**

Unfortunately, prior to PSv5, only the `Write-Host` cmdlet supports the `-NoNewline` parameter (introduced in v2), which is of no help here, so the .NET framework must be used:

```
powershell -Command "[IO.File]::WriteAllText(\"$PWD/file2.txt\", ((gc $PWD/file1.txt) -join \"`n\") + \"`n\")"
```

Note the need to use path prefix `$PWD` explicitly, because the .NET Framework's current directory typically differs from PowerShell's.

Also, the output file's **encoding will be UTF-8, without a BOM**, but you can pass a different encoding as the 3rd argument to `[IO.File]::WriteAllText()`, such as `[System.Text.Encoding]::Default` to match `Set-Content`'s default behavior (as of Windows PowerShell v5.1).

---

#### Optional reading: platform-specific line breaks `` "`n" `` vs. `` "`r`n" `` vs. `[Environment]::Newline`

***Implicit* choice of newlines** (line breaks):

- when *reading*, PowerShell accepts LF-only (Unix-style) and CRLF (Windows-style) newlines (line breaks) *interchangeably*.
- when *writing* (e.g., when sending an *array* of lines / objects to a file with `>` / `Out-File` / `Set-Content`), PowerShell uses the *platform-appropriate* newline sequence.
  Note, however, that any newline sequences *embedded* in a given *string* input object are sent to the file as-is.

As for **escape sequences / constants**:

- `[Environment]::Newline` contains the platform-appropriate newline.
- `` "`n" `` is *always* just LF (`\n`)

  - as evidenced by `` "`n".Length `` returning `1` and `` [char] 10 -eq [char] "`n" `` returning `$True` (`10` is the decimal Unicode/ASCII code point of LF).
  - The documentation isn't explicit about this: [`Get-Help about_Special_Characters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters) mentions "new line" and "line break", without mentioning what specific character [sequence] that represents. (As mentioned, LF by itself is just as valid a line break as CRLF is in PowerShell).
- Therefore, to create *CRLF* sequences, you must use `` "`r`n" ``.
- If you need to *match* newlines in *either* format, you can use [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) `'\r?\n'`, with operators such as [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch), [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator), and [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split)

As for ***multi-line string literals* in scripts** (including here-documents):

- They *reflect their source file's newline style*.  That is, if your script uses CRLF newlines, so will the newlines embedded in the multi-line string.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it from the PowerShell command line:

```
(Get-Content Input.txt -Raw) -replace "`r`n","`n" | Out-File Output.txt -Encoding ASCII -NoNewline
```

As others have noted this is a PowerShell v5 solution (`-Raw` appeared in v3, and `-NoNewline` appeared in v5).

Here's a PowerShell v2 version of the same thing:

```
$content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\Path\Input.txt") -replace "`r`n","`n"
[IO.File]::WriteAllText("C:\Path\Output.txt", $content)
```

(The paths are needed because the .NET methods don't use PowerShell's "current location".)