# Is it possible to write a " in a string, if yes how?

Tags: string, powershell, escaping

I need to write a `"` into a string, because a script needs it in the format, but I do not know how to do it.

Does it need to be marked as a character?

Comment: Have you ever heard of escaping characters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly escape quotes in powershell v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44637110/how-to-properly-escape-quotes-in-powershell-v2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escaping quotes and double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116186/escaping-quotes-and-double-quotes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to double it, put it inside a single quote or escape it with `` ` ``

```
echo "This will output a double quote """
echo '"This will also be put in double quotes"'
echo "`"This is another way to quote`""
```

For more string quoting basics refer to the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-6)